# 2 CollectionView inside the TableView Cell not working

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm working on ui that has basically two categories first is categories and second one is products when user click on any category the products load accordingly.Category showing in horizontal direction and products showing in vertical direction.I'm using tableView and inside the tableView cell I'm using two collectionViews.All outlets are connected when I running code (could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier CategoiresCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard") occurs.Also I'm using tableView height method I' want dynamically calculated and also in collectionView I'm using sizeForItemAt for calculating the height so how I can calculate the dynamically height accordingly to content in tableView as well as in collectionView according to tableViewcell.

I want this layout[image]

My code pics
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Error:
[image]

Comment: The code should be added as code snippets instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

We have had the had the same problem with sizing of TableViewCell and dealing with accessibility large font and collection views, the way we got around that was to get the table view cells to to relayout there contents a second time, it seem like the cell needs to layout there subview again with something like layoutIfNeeded, it was a work project, so I don't have access to anymore and can only go by memory, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.